# Using Functional Interface inside AtomicReference

Tags: java, concurrency

What could be the rationale behind using a Functional interface inside an [AtomicReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html)? Would it provide similar guarantees as `synchronized`? Or does it just provide visibility guarantees to the change to other threads as in `volatile`?

I came across the following example of using a [Predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) inside an `AtomicReference` that got me thinking:

https://github.com/corda/token-sdk/blob/master/modules/selection/src/main/kotlin/com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.selection/memory/services/VaultWatcherService.kt#L240

Comment: The above code sample is in Kotlin, but I guess it is more of a Java question. :)

Comment: Please put an example in your question rather than as a link.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the small code of getAndUpdate with functional interface.

```
public final V getAndUpdate(UnaryOperator<V> updateFunction) {
        V prev = get(), next = null;
        for (boolean haveNext = false;;) {
            if (!haveNext)
                next = updateFunction.apply(prev);
            if (weakCompareAndSetVolatile(prev, next))
                return prev;
            haveNext = (prev == (prev = get()));
        }
    }
```

Volatile help to guarantee about visibility of variables and weakCompareAndSetVolatile is make sure other thread don't change the value.
That's why functional interface still be safe when passing to AtomicReference.

https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.java

Comment: Visibility is only 1 part. Ordering and atomicity (even for loads/stores) are the 2 other parts.

Answer (score 0):

The key part that needs to be determined is that write and read of the shared variable should not be in a data race. You get a data race when you have 2 memory actions, to the same location,  at least one of them is a write, and the actions are not ordered by a happens-before edge.

There is a happens-before edge between a write of a volatile variable and all subsequent reads of that same variable. This edge is the result from the volatile variable rule.

For a synchronized block it is a bit more complicated.

If you would have something like this:

```
int a;


// thread 1
synchronized(this){
   a=1              (1)
}                   (2)

// thread 2
synchronized(this){ (3)
   int b=a          (4)
   ...
}
```

If the (2) synchronizes with (3) then the following holds:

(1) happens-before (2) due to program-order rule.

(2) happens-before (3) due to monitor-lock rule.

(3) happens-before (4) due to program-order rule.

Because happens-before is transitive, (1) happens-before (4).

So from a memory model perspective, volatile and synchronized are very comparable.

Back to the AtomicReference: is there a particular method you want to dive into?